# Как получить список объектов с не пустым ICollection свойством?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть код

```
private Dictionary<int, Сolor[]> colorSet = new Dictionary<int, int, Сolor[]>()
{
   {1, new Сolor[2] {Сolor.Red, Сolor.Green}},
   {2, new Сolor[2] {Сolor.Yellow, Сolor.Blue}},
   ...
};

public class Graph
{
   public Сolor Сolor { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Point> Points { get; set; }
}
```

1) Как получить List, которые имеют Points в базе

```
List<Graph> graphs = context.Graphs.Where(g => g.Points.Count > 0).ToList()
```

2) Как транслировать в linq to entities такой код

```
List<Graph> graphs = context.Graphs.Where(g => colorSet[1].Contains(g.Color)).ToList()
```

Получаю:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '...' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Такая конструкция рабочая

```
List<Graph> graphs = context.Graphs.Where(g => (new Сolor[2] {Сolor.Red, Сolor.Green}).Contains(g.Color)).ToList()
```

Comment: в чем проблема в 1-ом случае? что нужно сделать во втором?

Comment: В 1-м случае получаю все Graph вне зависимости от того, есть ли у него в базе Points или нет (условие игнорится). Во втором - написал ошибку

Comment: А можно привести полностью класс Graph? colorSet должет быть в нем я так понмаю?

Comment: Ошибку и код вижу. Напишите, что вы хотите получить во втором случае?

Comment: 1) Хочу отобрать все Graph, у которых нет связанных Points (две таблицы один ко многим). Я, конечно, могу приинклудить Points, получить List и затем выбрать Graph, у которых Points > 0. А можно ли получить все одним запросом (аналог if Exists(select 1 from ...))? 2) Как массив из Dictionary транслировать в sql-ный In. Linq to objects так сработает. Как то же самое сделать для context.Graphs? colorSet сам по себе.

Answer (score 4):

В первом случае все должно работать. Хотя лучше использовать Any:

```
var graphs = context.Graphs.Where(g => g.Points.Any()).ToList();
```

Во втором случае EF не может странслировать индексатор. Поэтому придется массив сохранить в переменную, а потом ей воспользоваться:

```
var colors = colorSet[1];
var graphs = context.Graphs.Where(g => colors.Contains(g.Color)).ToList();
```